# Running Erlang project on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, erlang, remote-server

We have a project with different processes, and run it by calling `erl -pa ebin`, `mymodule_supervisor:start_link().`

We have set up an ubuntu instance on Amazon EC2. Being new to this, how can we run the project remotely, so we can close the connection and the project will continue to run?

We can run the Erlang shell in the background, but we can't our project on it. It would be perfect to see an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method 1:** You could build a release package from your code. If done right, this will embed a complete Erlang system (along with your application and its dependencies) in an easily distributable tar file. Using an automatically generated script the node can then be started as a daemon, running in the background even after you close your shell.

A good way to get started is to use [Rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar), which already supports [release handling](https://github.com/basho/rebar/wiki/Release-handling) out of the box.

**Method 2:** Use tmux or screen (both easily installed on Ubuntu) to start your node and detach the session. If you choose tmux, the following should work:

1. Start tmux simply by running `tmux` from a shell.
2. From within tmux, start your node with the `erl` command as before.
3. Detach your session using `Ctrl-b` followed by `d`. Exit your shell. The node should still be running.

---

The "proper" way to start the supervisor is to call its `start_link` function from within the `start` function of your Erlang [application](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html).